# JQuery page scroll animation only works in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have the following two html files. When you click on the link in the first page (a.html), it will open a second page (b.html) and scroll down to the relevant place. I have added a JQuery animation to the scroll. This works perfectly in chrome but not in other browsers such as firefox and IE.

a.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>




    </head>

    <body>

       <a href="b.html#elementID">Jump</a>

</body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('html, body').hide();

        if (window.location.hash) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                    }, 1000)
            }, 0);
        }
        else {
            $('html, body').show();
        }
    });
</script>


</head>

<body>





<div style="margin-top:4000px" id="elementID">AAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>
<h1>AAAAAAA</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox force browser to go to hash tag's location by default. you need to reset `scrollTop` on page load then make an animate like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('html, body').hide();

        if (window.location.hash) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
                $('html, body').prop('scrollTop',0).animate({
                    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                    }, 1000)
            }, 0);
        }
        else {
            $('html, body').show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
You have to scroll after your page loads with the data.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
     $('html, body').show();
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('html, body')[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);

     }
```